# How do i install drupal 7 on tomacat server

Tags: tomcat, drupal, drupal-7

I'm new to Drupal. I googled for installation of Drupal on Tomcat server but i couldn't find any procedure for installation.

Can anyone tell the procedure for installation of Drupal 7 on Tomcat server in windows 7 environment?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can u please give the reason for down Voting

Comment: Is it possible to install Drupal on tomcat server.  I would really appreciate any help. Great thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Install the following packages php5-cgi php5-gd php5-mysql tomcat mysql-server in your system.

Download the PHP/Java Bridge from http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-java-bridge/files/Binary%20package/p...

Download and extract drupal in your system.

Move the "JavaBridgeTemplate621.war" file to the Tomcat webapps directory. Wait a few seconds for Tomcat to create a "JavaBridgeTemplate621" directory.

sudo cp JavaBridgeTemplate621.war /opt/tomcat/webapps/

Copy the directory created by Tomcat and name it "drutomcat".

sudo cp -R /opt/tomcat/webapps/JavaBridgeTemplate621 /opt/tomcat/webapps/drutomcat

Remove the index.php and test.php files from the "drutomcat" directory.

sudo rm /opt/tomcat/webapps/drutomcat/index.php
sudo rm /opt/tomcat/webapps/drutomcat/test.php

Copy the Drupal files to the "drutomcat" directory, create the "settings.php" file.

sudo cp -R drupal/ /opt/tomcat/webapps/drutomcat
sudo cp /opt/tomcat/webapps/drutomcat/drupal/sites/default/default.settings.php /opt/tomcat/webapps/drutomcat/drupal/sites/default/settings.php

Now point to your browser by typing http: // localhost :8080 / drutomcat /drupal and run the drupal installer

Comment: I am able to install tomcat ,mysql server in my PC but unable to install " php5-cgi php5-gd php5-mysql".can you please provide the installation procedure for the above mentioned packages @Naim FS

Comment: r u using windows/kinux.?

Comment: i am using windows 7 @Naim FS

Comment: I too found the above procedure in google but unable to install " php5-cgi php5-gd php5-mysql" @NaimFS

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit surprising.

Tomcat is primarily targeted to Java/JEE applications, not PHP (like Drupal).

Though, you may be able to install Drupal on Tomcat : I found this link :

https://groups.drupal.org/node/180139

It's outdated (2011), but may be still relevant. It involves installing a PHP/Java bridge.

Unless you really need Drupal on Tomcat, I would suggest you install a WAMP environment (Apache / PHP + MySQL).

Note : first answer posted just copy pasted the contents of the link I provided...please always add the source !!

Comment: For front end we targeted to java/JEE applications only. @user7